# Conceptually struggling with a free particle moving in 3 dimensions. Is my reasoning provided below flawed in any way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

[image: This is a problem I have been trying to reason through conceptually for a few days now regarding a free particle moving in 3 dimensions.]

I am struggling conceptually with this problem regarding momentum $\vec{p}$ and position $\vec{r}$ representation. As far as I can tell, momentum $\vec{p}$ should not rely on time $t$, and neither position $\vec{r}$ or momentum $\vec{p}$ should depend upon one another. However, when I broke this problem down three-dimensionally, I ended up with a time derivative $d\over dt$ in front of my expectation values for both momentum $\vec{p}$ and position $\vec{r}$. The way I defined the expectation values are as follows: $d\over dt$ $<$ $p^{2}$ $>$ and $d\over dt$ $<$ $r^{2}$ $>$. As far as I understand, this is not correct because the momentum $\vec{p}$ should not depend on time. Is my reasoning flawed in any way?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: $\langle \textbf{p}|\psi(t)\rangle := \psi(\textbf{p}, t)$ is the *fourier-transform* of $\langle \textbf{r}|\psi(t)\rangle := \psi(\textbf{r},t)$.